# UWP: Folder in AppPackages is different from Package Family Name

Tags: deployment, uwp, visual-studio-2019

I am developing a UWP app with Visual Studio 2019 Community 16.6.3.

When I run the app in Debug, Visual Studio deploys the app on my machine, creating a folder under

```
C:\Users\<MY_USER>\AppData\Local\Packages\
```

but the folder is named differently from the Package Family Name in my Package.appxmanifest.

Therefore (I guess), my connection to the MS Store is not working (I receive an error when I invoke the Store APIs) and also the OneDrive integration is broken.

Please note that my colleagues do not have any problem with the very same code-base (but they are working with Visual Studio 2019 Professional 16.5.5).

Is it a problem of the specific version of Visual Studio or is there anything in my code, in my machine or in my configurations that I should tweak?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> Is it a problem of the specific version of Visual Studio or is there anything in my code

Please check if has modified the project's package family name, for the testing Visual Studio 2019 16.7.0 does not reproduce this issue. Please try to update the VS to latest version and delete installed app and re-build again.